# How to match only first occurence of a string per line with regex

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a regex pattern `-\w{8}-` to retrieve certain data but I only want to receive the first occurrence of this on every line

The data I have is

```
access-list xxx line 328 extended permit object-group RLS-Test-5ee67f4d-service-ports
access-list xxx line 329 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports123-
access-list xxx line 330 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports
access-list xxx line 331 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports-openwire-2
access-list xxx line 332 extended permit object-group RLS-Test-2-73d6bba4-service-ports-openwire-1
access-list xxx line 333 extended permit object-group RLS-Test-2-73d6bba4-service-ports-openwire-2
access-list xxx line 334 extended permit object-group SQL-85145d21-web-ports
access-list xxx line 335 extended permit object-group SQL-85145d21-open-access
access-list xxx line 336 extended permit object-group SQl-85145d21-open-access
```

I want it to return:

```
-5ee67f4d-
-564dcfd5-
-73d6bba4-
-85145d21-
```

But if I use the regex `-\w{8}-` it will also select other words of 8 characters between hyphens further along the string. See https://regex101.com/r/1rS2Gl/4/

Is there a way I can only select the first per line? I have tried other methods but seem to result in only returning the first line and omitting the rest of the data.

Comment: Use an anchor with a non greedy quantifier and a capturing group `^.*?(-\w{8}-)` https://regex101.com/r/Gok5FG/1 or use [re.seach](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to get the first location.

Comment: Isn't there a programmatically way setting a limit in python? However if you use a capturing group, it might be even more efficient to just consume the part after first occurence. See [this updated demo](https://regex101.com/r/1rS2Gl/5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your strings have the same character set as a standard GUID. Try `-[abcdef0-9]{8}-` to limit it to hex digits.

Comment: This, however, will extract multiple occurrences per line anyway, OP needs to only get the first occurrence on a line.

Answer (score 1):

Read the text or file line by line and use `re.search` to find the first occurrence on each line, and collect Group 1 values:

```
import re
data = """access-list xxx line 329 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports123-
access-list xxx line 330 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports
access-list xxx line 331 extended permit object-group WEB-564dcfd5-service-ports-openwire-2
access-list xxx line 332 extended permit object-group RLS-Test-2-73d6bba4-service-ports-openwire-1
access-list xxx line 333 extended permit object-group RLS-Test-2-73d6bba4-service-ports-openwire-2
access-list xxx line 334 extended permit object-group SQL-85145d21-web-ports
access-list xxx line 335 extended permit object-group SQL-85145d21-open-access
access-list xxx line 336 extended permit object-group SQl-85145d21-open-access"""
results = []

rx = re.compile(r'-(\w{8})-')

for line in data.splitlines():
    m = rx.search(line)
    if m:
        results.append(m.group(1))
        # Use results.append(m.group()) if you really need to include hyphens

print(results)
# => ['564dcfd5', '564dcfd5', '564dcfd5', '73d6bba4', '73d6bba4', '85145d21', '85145d21', '85145d21']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HLDXOJ) (and [this demo](https://ideone.com/oO2w2b) outputs matches with hyphens).